# Sort by Column C but group the values from Column F

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

For simplicity, I would like it to be separated by country (written at the beginning of the names in Column C), but those that have data in Column F stay together, and those that don't have it are separated.

`=QUERY(Sheet7!B1:G,"Where C is not null Order by C")`

[image]

> In the country Brazil it is noted that the lines with values in F are
>   not grouped. This is what I would like to group together, in
>   alphabetical order as in Column C, but in the list of each country
>   came first those with data in Column F.

I tried to use Query with Group by after referring a member (Player0), the first answer to the question, but unfortunately I was not able to get what I need to do.

**Right way would be:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here result will sort the country and F:

```
= array_constrain 
  ( arrayformula 
    ( query
      ( SORT
        ( { Sheet7!B1:G, 
            mid (Sheet7!C1:C,1,find("/",Sheet7!C1:C,find("/",Sheet7!C1:C,2)+1)), 
            Sheet7!F1:F
          }
          , 7, true, 8, true
        ) 
        ,"Select *" 
      )
    )
    ,ROWS(Sheet7!B1:B),6
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use `group by` then you always need to use some aggregation function like:

- sum
- avg
- max
- min
- count

for example:

```
=QUERY(Sheet7!B1:G, "select C,count(C) where C is not null group by F order by C")
```

Comment: Thanks mate... I am trying to select all columns (B,C,D,E,F,G) to be part of the query results but when I do this an error appears: > ADD_COL_TO_GROUP_BY_OR_AGG: B

Comment: if you `select B,C,D` then you also need to add those into group by `B,C,D`

Comment: Ahhh Ok! I understand now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually without any aggregate can't use group by, so I modify your formula:

```
=QUERY(Sheet7!B1:G,"select min(B), min(C), min(D), min(E), F  Where C is not null Group By F Order by min(C) label min(B) '', min(C) '', min(D) '', min(E) ''")
```

explanation:

```
1. min(B), min(C), min(D), min(E) or max(B), max(C), max(D), max(E), 
   just as some aggregates, because you group the query by F

2. label min(B) '', min(C) '', min(D) '', min(E) ''", to not use title
```

Or if you don't need aggregate, you can use sort formula

```
Filter(sort(Sheet7!B1:G,5,true, 2, true),Sheet7!C1:C<>"")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, but when I try to do via query as you indicated, a very big error appears. Link to error: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T5pap7T0N_8LeyxAC9waOsARpq_YizBJDoNXYpcZRCM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In that case I really needed to get them all together from the same country together. I cannot filter and separate entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately a lot of data has disappeared in this filter, only a few rows left and the results are totally out of position.

What I would like is to continue all existing data, sort by country (column C), and only separate data that contained values in F and those that do not.

But I believe that by formula it is impossible to achieve by what I am analyzing.

Comment: Ok Try with this =query(Sheet7!B1:G,"Select * where B is not null order by C,F")

Comment: Thanks for support mate but that way I had tried, but he can't separate the F-owners from the non-Fs because he first ranks C. So the first sort rule blocks the second.

Comment: how about if you change  to =query(Sheet7!B1:G,"Select * where B is not null order by F,C")

Comment: Thanks mate, but In this way the values ​​are divided between those with values ​​in F and those without. Creating a total division. It is not grouped by country.

I believe there really is no option for what I need.

Comment: I make a new Answer as you need